# Application crashes in splash screen using iPhone 12 Pro Max

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developing Xamarin.Forms app. I can deploy and launch the app in a iPhone X, but the app crashes in a iPhone 12 Pro Max. Both iPhones have iOS 14.7.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.10.4 and Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2083.

This is the content of the output window, with native report. Do you know what is happening?

```
2021-07-28 09:01:34.162 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005548] Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 6

2021-07-28 09:01:34.165 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005548] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'

2021-07-28 09:01:34.165 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.exe [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Library.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
2021-07-28 09:01:34.402 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBF79CC9-237C-400B-AFA4-619FA7E20CCC/Documents/MyApp.iOS.content

Thread started:  #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
2021-07-28 09:01:34.653 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Forms app path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBF79CC9-237C-400B-AFA4-619FA7E20CCC/Documents/MyApp.iOS.content/MyApp.iOS.exe

2021-07-28 09:01:34.654 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

2021-07-28 09:01:34.654 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

2021-07-28 09:01:34.654 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' (culture: '')
2021-07-28 09:01:34.655 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBF79CC9-237C-400B-AFA4-619FA7E20CCC/Documents/MyApp.iOS.content/MyApp.iOS.exe
2021-07-28 09:01:34.656 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'MyApp' (culture: '')

2021-07-28 09:01:34.656 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'MyApp' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBF79CC9-237C-400B-AFA4-619FA7E20CCC/Documents/MyApp.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBF79CC9-237C-400B-AFA4-619FA7E20CCC/Documents/MyApp.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FBF79CC9-237C-400B-AFA4-619FA7E20CCC/Documents/MyApp.iOS.content/MyApp.dll
2021-07-28 09:01:34.682 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[6171:3005529] Xamarin.Forms AppDelegate name: AppDelegate


=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x10037c120 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info

    0x100372cbc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x10037fa60 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x1ee4e029c - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>

    0x1a239b5ec - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a238b008 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a239b418 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a238b948 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a239bf30 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a239b9c0 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a239d928 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a238eecc - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>
    0x100528970 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x100527010 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x10051da8c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x10051beb0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E89227
89cf8 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x10671b3a0):0x10671b390  e2 59 00 10 1f 20 03 d5 1c 07 00 94 e7 ff ff 17  .Y... ..........
0x10671b3a0  ff c3 00 d1 fd 7b 02 a9 fd 83 00 91 a0 ff ff 10  .....{..........
0x10671b3b0  1f 20 03 d5 e1 03 00 91 1a 07 00 94 a0 01 00 34  . .............4
0x10671b3c0  e8 07 40 f9 08 0d 40 b9 1f 09 00 71 1f 20 03 d5  ..@...@....q. ..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:_dlopen <0x00026>
      at ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn:dlopen <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:LoadFrameworks <0x0009e>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x00202>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <
0x00092>
=================================================================

9/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x100382d3c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1004312c0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x100436564 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x1003678f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x100519984 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main
    0x10032fc34 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B617F18-EB5B-40B3-96D4-18688E892279/MyApp.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x1a23
The app has been terminated.
```

**Edit 1:**

To add more details about comments questions. I'm working with paired Mac and connected to the iPhone using USB cable.

**1) Power Off the phone, and power it back on.** After that I can deploy the application to, but the debugger is disconnected (Run button is enabled again), so I can't debug or read logs in the output window.

**2) Manually Uninstall (delete) the app from the phone.** After test 1) and 2) the result is the same: debugger is disconnected.

**3) Is this Debug or Release build? Please show the Build Options you have set.** I'm working in Debug:

[image: Build Options]

**4) If you run App on an iPhone Simulator choosing iPhone 12 Pro Max, what happens?** Using iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS 14.5 simulator I get an error about a library (MyLibrary in the logs):

```
Native linking failed. Please review the build log. MyApp.iOS           
warning: ignoring file /Users/macuser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/16c7bc9b0e8af1f53dbbdd4467006ec97d5efb9ff993c29d61d5200ba9ab2640/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/Curve25519.framework/Curve25519, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64  MyApp.iOS           
Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: SwiftFrameworkProxy. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SwiftFrameworkProxy' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.  MyApp.iOS           
warning: ignoring file /Users/macuser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/16c7bc9b0e8af1f53dbbdd4467006ec97d5efb9ff993c29d61d5200ba9ab2640/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/SwiftFrameworkProxy.framework/SwiftFrameworkProxy, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64    MyApp.iOS           
warning: ignoring file /Users/macuser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/16c7bc9b0e8af1f53dbbdd4467006ec97d5efb9ff993c29d61d5200ba9ab2640/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/SwiftProtobuf.framework/SwiftProtobuf, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64    MyApp.iOS           
warning: ignoring file /Users/macuser/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/16c7bc9b0e8af1f53dbbdd4467006ec97d5efb9ff993c29d61d5200ba9ab2640/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/MyLibrary.framework/MyLibrary, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64    MyApp.iOS           
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   MyApp.iOS
```

**5) Is XCode on your build Mac up-to-date?** Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507), the current latest version.

Comment: Actions to try (if you haven't already done so) 1) Power Off the phone, and power it back on. 2) Manually Uninstall (delete) the app from the phone. 3) Is this Debug or Release build? Please show the Build Options you have set. 4) If you run App on an iPhone Simulator choosing iPhone 12 Pro Max, what happens? 5) Is XCode on your build Mac up-to-date?

Comment: Hello @ToolmakerSteve, I edited the question adding the information your are asking for.